# How can I update a model on the Django admin page when the model is click to be viewed?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have a function that updates my Orders model. In my admin.py, I register the model, and have a `admin.ModelAdmin` class associated with it. I want to call a function that runs when the registered model is clicked on the admin page, so that it updates before the users sees any information about the orders. I've tried just adding the function:

```
class OrdersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    update_orders()
```

But this just results in it being updated when I run the server, and not when the "Orders" model is clicked in the admin. I've looked into admin `actions`, but that is only related to making changes to various fields of the model after the page is populated with objects from Orders Model.
How can I pass a function to be called when I click on the model in the admin page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do this is to override the get_absolute_url method in your model [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).

```
def get_absolute_url(self):

    #update you orders here .....

    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse('admin:yourapp_yourmodel_change', args=[str(self.id)])
```